# WLST Best Practices: Shell vs MBeans?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

Are there any admins out there who use WLST?

On our project we are in the process of automating many of our day-to-day tasks such as deployments and domain settings. We're also building scripts that will create domains based on our baseline configurations, JDBC, JNDI, etc.

One of the features offered through WLST is the navigation of MBeans through a shell-like interface. When it comes to making large scripts is this shell interface better or just calling the domain MBeans directly?

Any other tips/best-practices/pitfalls for using WLST?

Does anybody actually use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interactive mode is great for getting instant feedback on the behavior of functions. Having the whole startup, connection, session-init is time-consuming and the interactive mode of wlst avoids this.

The biggest pitfalls I found were first the difference between wlst-online and wlst-offline. And secondly the difference between the Wlst-env and the pure Python-env.

I can not imagine anyone scaling their WLS setup above 10 servers with more that 100 resources each without resorting to WLST to keep it manageable and consistent.